# set follow-fork-mode ask in fedora

Tags: gdb, fork

According to the document (https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_chapter/gdb_5.html#SEC26), follow-fork-mode in gdb can be set to ask.

However, I tried on my machine (fedora-21 32bit).

(gdb) set follow-fork-mode ask

Undefined item: "ask".

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a manual for a very old version of gdb.  Instead you should look at the manual corresponding to the gdb you are actually using. [Current versions of gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Debugging-Forks) don't allow `ask` here -- just `parent` or `child`.